# java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH permission error in Android project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth

```
07-12 16:15:49.169 20612-20675/? E/BluetoothAdapter: java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH permission: Neither user 10396 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH.
     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
     at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothManager$Stub$Proxy.registerStateChangeCallback(IBluetoothManager.java:342)
     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.<init>(BluetoothAdapter.java:594)
     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(BluetoothAdapter.java:576)
     at ru.mail.android.mytracker.providers.NetworkInfoDataProvider.collectData(SourceFile:90)
     at ru.mail.android.mytracker.providers.FingerprintDataProvider.collectData(SourceFile:92)
     at ru.mail.android.mytracker.async.commands.AbstractHttpCommand.execute(SourceFile:67)
     at ru.mail.android.mytracker.async.commands.TrackMajorEventsCommand.execute(SourceFile:117)
     at ru.mail.android.mytracker.async.commands.AbstractAsyncCommand.run(SourceFile:58)
     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:154)
     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

My android project show above exception when I running my app in android studio. Actually my app is not using BLUETOOTH. May I know why this error is show without using BLUETOOTH?

Comment: *Actually my app is not using BLUETOOTH.* the logs say something else. Show the code that causes it please

Comment: Maybe you have copy paste a project to your project and the first uses bluetooth

Comment: Show the code where your app showing this error

Comment: The Stacktrace shows that you are using the MyTracker (ru.mail.android.mytracker) library which uses Bluetooth and causes this log message.